# POST http://localhost:3000/createUser 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, json, internal-server-error

The server works perfectly fine in POSTMAN but will not work in the browser and gives a 500 Internal Server Error when creating a new user.
I double check my backend and everything is as it should be.

These are the error in my console log

1. **Login.js:31** POST http://localhost:3000/createUser 500 (Internal Server Error)

- 31 fetch('/createUser', options)

2. **Login.js:44** SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'P', "Proxy erro"... is not valid JSON

- 44 console.log(error);
- This was also in the console response

:
*Proxy error: Could not proxy request /createUser from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:1299/ (HPE_CR_EXPECTED).*

This is the error in my server log

1. Proxy error: Could not proxy request /createUser from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:1299/

Here is the full block of code:

```
function register() {
        setMessage('');
        const userDto = {
            userName: userName,
            password: password,
       };
31      console.log(userDto);
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(userDto)
        };
        fetch('/createUser', options)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((apiRes) => {
                console.log(apiRes);
                if (apiRes.status) {
                    setUserName('');
                    setPassword('');
                    setMessage('Your account has been created!');
                } else {
                    setMessage(apiRes.message);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
44              console.log(error);
                setMessage('User was not created, SERVER ERROR');
            });
    }
```

I have tried:

- Changing my proxy in package.json
- Changing header to 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
- Double checking to correct JSON
- Clearing my browser and cache
- Double checking back-end server for mistakes

Comment: http 500 status means it's a server error - no server code, so not sure what you did wrong - you're sending JSON, so you will want `Changing header to 'Content-Type': 'application/json'` - the response is not JSON, so that's why the error is what it is - the error suggests your server is expecting something other than JSON - so, the content-type header should fix it (or at least, you'll get a different error if you've done something else wrong)

Comment: Could it be the way I start my back end server? I run both servers in visual studio using the terminal., but it does say socket is open.

Comment: no idea - if adding the content-type header doesn't at least change the error, then, the server code at you haven't shown at :3000 is probably at fault

Comment: Ah, I'll keep looking. I appreciate your time to give me some insite.